# Phonegap: Unable to start receiver NullPointerException

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I found an android app. You can see it here: https://github.com/ChrLipp/SmsReceiver-Phonegap

When I run it it receives a text message and displays it on the screen. However if the app is closed and a text is received the phone crashes and the above error is returned (unable to start receiver). However in the logs it looks like the app is still able to get the message data (which is what i want) but then crashes.

Any advice?

Basically I want a app that when it closes/runs to background still is able to get the data from the text and do something with it.

Comment: You should write bug report to ChrLipp at github.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't launch the application, this is not called in onCreate():

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 1);
```

Then in the receiver, this return null:

```
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
```

which leads to a crash in the receiver and thus you have the unable to start receiver error.